# Updating multiple SQL records from x to x in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have 30+ records that need to be updated to have some of the same billing information. I don't want to have to type in every single number from 1200-1237. Is there an easy way to update all these records without copy/paste and altering the numbers? Possibly use a count?

EX:

```
UPDATE LakeEncroachments
SET PERMITEE = 3304, BILLTOPERSON = 3304, 
    LakeEncroachments.InvoiceBillTo = 1799 
WHERE LakeEncroachments.EN_ID = 1200, LakeEncroachments.EN_ID = 1201, LakeEncroachments.EN_ID = 12xx
```

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  It is very hard to understand what you might be asking for, given that there are no numbers in the range of "00" to "37" in your sample code.

Comment: I added the numbers to be 1200-1237

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

Provided EN_ID is numeric

```
UPDATE LakeEncroachments
SET 
   PERMITEE = 3304, BILLTOPERSON = 3304, LakeEncroachments.InvoiceBillTo = 1799 
WHERE 
   LakeEncroachments.EN_ID BETWEEN 1200 AND 12037
```